# AutoMapper - Map objects' properties (from object array to string array)

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have two similar objects that I am mapping to each other using AutoMapper. I create the map by doing the following:

```cs
CreateMap<Object1, Object2>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
   .ForMember(d => d.Description, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
```

Now `Object1` has a property `Object3[] listOfObject3` this `Object3` has an `Id` property which I want to map to my `Object2` property with `string[] listOfObject3Ids`

I tried the following but that doesn't work:

```cs
CreateMap<Object1, Object2>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
   .ForMember(d => d.Description, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
   .ForMember(d => d.listOfObject3.Id, o => o.MapFrom(s => new [] {s.Id})
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: Your question is wrong. You are mapping from Object1 to Object2, therefore your Object1 has the property `string[] listOfObject3Ids` and not Object2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map like this:

```
    CreateMap<Object1, Object2>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
        .ForMember(d => d.Description, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
        .ForMember(d => d.ListOfObject3, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.listOfObject3Ids.Select(id => new Object3 { Id = id })));
```

But as I already commented I am assuming your Object2 contains the list of Object3 and your Object1 contains the list with the ids. Then you could map like this:

```
CreateMap<Object1, Object2>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
                .ForMember(d => d.Description, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
                .ForMember(d => d.listOfObject3Ids, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.ListOfObject3.Select(o => o.Id)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides @Sebastian's answer to work with *System.Linq* which is correct,

you can also work with `.ConvertUsing()` method.

1. Create mapping from `Object3` to `string` and via `.ConvertUsing()`.
2. Map member from `Object1.listOfObject3` to `Object2.listOfObject3Ids`.

```cs
CreateMap<Object3, string>()
    .ConvertUsing((src) => src.Id);
            
CreateMap<Object1, Object2>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
    .ForMember(d => d.Description, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
    .ForMember(d => d.listOfObject3Ids, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.listOfObject3));
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QtOucx)

---

**Reference**

[Custom Type Converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html)

Comment: Nice option, this is new to me :)